# Is there a setting for HTML Canvas drawing to always draw my exact color without feathering or approximating for a better visual?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, webgl, drawing

I'm writing a webapp to draw a segmentation map which will then be used as input into a neural network to generate a realistic looking image. For a better picture, I use a mapping from the 150 segmentation classes (labeled 1 through 150, single channel) to RGB so that they aren't drawing in hard-to-distinguish black and white colors. I use a few dictionaries for the forward and backward mappings.

My problem is that when I use the following code to draw lines, the canvas seems to add/multiply colors instead of use the exact stroke color I'm using, causing a keyerror in my python backend.

```
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.lineWidth = size;
ctx.lineJoin = "round";
ctx.lineCap = "round";
ctx.moveTo(lastx, lasty);
ctx.lineTo(x, y);
ctx.closePath();
ctx.stroke();
```

Here is an image of my tool, and an example of my drawing a single line (the green trail on the olive background). The starting image is drawn with fill rect, by the way.

Example image:
[image]

I've verified that there is no issues if I just draw rectangles with `ctx.fillRect(Math.round(x-size/2), Math.round(y-size/2), size, size)`, but of course it's not as pretty.

Both the fill and stroke color are the same. I've tried all combinations of lineJoin and lineCap for the line drawing. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Applying_styles_and_colors has helpful information, but doesn't offer a solution to never draw the "half" pixels. Is there a setting I'm overlooking?

Comment: On your sample image, I can not see any color difference... can you provide a: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: If you're using `const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')` then you shouldn't tag your question with `webgl`. That's a completely different api.

Comment: Precisely, the color difference is negligible, but it is not the exact color. Here is a zoomed in example: https://imgur.com/a/yeOASRb. You can see that it blends on the edges that aren't perfectly on the pixel. @HelderSepulveda

Comment: Did the `ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled= false`  fixed it?

Comment: @HelderSepulveda unfortunately, no :(

Comment: This post has been officially closed as a duplicate and the answer it links to is the  `imageSmoothingEnabled` maybe close this question and ask a new one?   ...and if you do please include working code to reproduce: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example